# Populating backbone collection with empty models as placeholders

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm writing a web application using backbone. I am going to display a list of thumbnails in grid format on a webpage.

I have created a view called PhotosView, which is listening to backbone collection

```
PhotosView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template( $('#container').html() ),
```

Then for each photo I've created another view, which represents each thumbnail in that list

```
EachPhotoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#thumbnail').html()),
```

Photos view is listening to a collection, and on reset event it creates EachPhotoView for all the photos that are to be displayed. EachPhotoView then listens to a model associated with it for change event.

I'm now trying to paginate these thumbnail. I'm now going to ask for only those thumbnails that are in view, but I still have to create placeholders for all the images.

So my question is, is it a good idea to populate collection with number of empty backbone models, and In future when I actually get those models, replace them from collections. This will solve my problem of having placeholder. Is there any other way of doing this?

---

EDIT: I'm talking about a grid layout of thumbnails, say 500 on a single page, and as you scroll down, I'm requesting parts in those 500. I have to create all placeholders ( all 500 ) thumbnails, because that would give container div appropriate height (for 500 images) so I have to have all 500 models in the collection ( although dummy ) that will help me attach events on the view to those empty models and as I get those thumbnails metadata, I'll add it in it's corresponding model in collection.

Comment: What do you mean by Placeholders?

Comment: empty model with default attributes that is attached to a view, so view shows some kind of generic image till actual image is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `Model` that are in place already has a record associated with it somewhere, I assume. If not, your `Data Source` should contain them and your client-side `View` will render them based on that `Collection` records. The only thing missing is, the corresponding `Image` is currently not available for some of these records.

Those `Models` will have a property of `imgSource` that will be empty. Your `View` will then handle and perform a check if whether the `imgSource` property is empty and replace it some default `Thumbnail`.

```
<img src="<%- imgSource ==='' ? '/images/default.jpg' : '/images/'+ imgSource %>" 
   alt="imgDesc" />
```

Comment: Yes every model has a data associated with it in the backend, but currently it's completely empty ( not just urls but id's as well ) I'm then going to request them and add all those attributes to it's corresponding model as you scroll. I want to know if it's the right way of doing it, or is there a better way

Comment: Why don't you add an `id` on them as well and treat them like actual records? It should be fine either way though but I don't see it being an issue not having it as actual `Models` with an `id` since they can be removed or edited for whatever reason.

Comment: Because I can't get ID's when until I actually call the service ( assuming id on client model is same as id of that object represented on backend )

Comment: Right, so insert those records in the DB and do a fetch() on it. If you can't do that than you can just hard code your `Models` temporarily and swap it out when those records gets inserted in the DB.

Comment: I think if you swap the models, it will remove all the events that are attached to that model, am I right?

Comment: The events are tied to the `Model` at time of declaration so essentially, you can bind to those events at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you will have a grid of thumbmails (say 30 thumbnails) and back/forward buttons.

What I would do is make your collection represent ONLY the items in view and use your back/forward buttons to alter a this.page property and then re-`fetch()` the entire collection (replacing the 30 thumbnails inside with 30 on the next page).

[This piece of code](https://gist.github.com/io41/838460) is a good example of how to set up a paginated collection and your paginated view.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough. I'm talking about a grid layout of thumbnails, say 500 on a single page, and as you scroll down, I'm requesting more and more. I have create all placeholders ( all 500 ) thumbnails, because the would give container div appropriate height so I have to have all 500 models in the collection ( although dummy )